# Vue js model binding for jQuery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using jQuery date picker and its working perfectly. I am in Vue component. when I click the date input field it shows date picker but when I choose one date and see the result in the console I got nothing. Date is not bind.

```
<form @submit.prevent="search()">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header"></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" v-model="date"  class="form-control" id="datepicker" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" >Search</button>

                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </form>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                date:''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        methods:{
            search(){
         //I want to get user chooses date here so that I can send to endpoint
                console.log(this.date)//got nothing here
          
            },
          

        },
   
    }
</script
```

> 

when i click the search button , i should get the date in console but i got nothing, How to get current selected date by user? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the input inside `mounted` hook with the jquery date picker.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      date: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.');
    let selfInstance = this;
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(selected, datePicker) {
        selfInstance.date = selected;
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      //I want to get user chooses date here so that I can send to endpoint
      console.log(this.date) //got nothing here

    },


  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<form id="app" @submit.prevent="search">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" v-model="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

**Note**: `this.date` will not work inside the jquery blocks. So an instance should be defined to assign with vue.